# How to create a neural network with dynamic number of output nodes?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to create a neural network that attempts to identify rectangles in a given picture. Since a picture can contain an unpredictable number of rectangles, how should I represent the nodes in my output layer?

Or is it inappropriate to use neural networks in this case? If so, what algorithm should I use?

**Update: My problem is very similar to how face recognition works. The one which puts a rectangle around a human face. That algorithm can identify a dynamic number of faces in a picture. I want to do something like that but for simpler shapes.**

Answer (score 0):

What programming language are you using?
I don't think that a neural network will be useful in this case. Because it will be very hard to train the neural network to recognize rectangles with eventually not good results. And the output layer of a neural network shouldn't be dynamic (that's not how they work). 
Another way you could do this is by digital image processing. Matlab is good or octave (for open source). The concept is that you apply a digital filter (which is a table 3x3 or something like that) to your image to "filter" the rectangles you want. So if you are familiar with digital image processing follow that way, if not it's no use.

Comment: I plan on using C# as my language. I understand what you mean, but how does face recognition work? The one which puts a rectangle around a human face? That algorithm can identify a dynamic number of faces in a picture. I want to do something like that but for simpler shapes.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is a Single Shot Detector(SSD). It can identify multiple objects on a picture or objects at multiple places on a picture.